# Django REST multipart data converted to string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, django-serializer, django-validation

Passing a JSON + image data to a post endpoint, ends in converting part of request data to string. The part which is converted to string contains the file as well. Here is the input data:

```
data = {
    "external": "90000001",
    "sales": [
        {
            "total": 4,
            "quantities": {"xs": 2, "s": 4},
            "product": {
                "type": self.type.id,
                "product_image": {
                    "name": "First test files",
                    "product_files": [
                        {
                            # "file": base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode(),
                            "file": test_file,
                            "description": "Patterns file.",
                            "type": "pattern_file",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
        }
    ],
}
```

I am sending request to my endpoint in the test in this way:

```
res: Response = self.client.post(self.create_ext_so_url, data)
```

It returns an error:

> rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'sales': [ErrorDetail(string='Must specify at least one sales', code='blank')]}

Here is the sales data extracted in the `run_validation(...)`

```
>>> attrs.get("sales", [])
"{'total': 4, 'quantities': {'xs': 2, 's': 4}, 'product': {'type': 1, 'product_image': {'name': 'First test files', 'product_files': [{'file': <SimpleUploadedFile: test.svg (image/svg+xml)>, 'description': 'Patterns file.', 'type': 'pattern_file'}]}}}"
```

Here it is visible that the sales in converted to string and later it won't be available as an object/dictionary and the object won't be created, which makes it fail the test.

Here is the view if someone wants to check it.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["POST"], url_path="create-sales")
def create_sales_order(self, request: Request)-> Response:
    ser_class = self.get_serializer_class()   
    ser = ser_class(data=request.data)
    ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    ser.save()
    return Response(ser.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The serializers are defined like this:

```
class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer[Order]):
    order_lines = LineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, attrs: Any) -> Any:
        order_lines = [
            item for item in attrs.get("order_lines", []) if not is_empty_object(item)
        ]
        if (
            not order_lines
            or not isinstance(order_lines, list)
            or len(order_lines) == 0
        ):
            raise ValidationError(
                {"order_lines": ["Must specify at least one order line"]},
                code="blank",
            )
        for line in order_lines:
            if not line.get("product", None):
                raise ValidationError(
                    {
                        "order_lines": [
                            "Cannot create Order Line without a Porduct on it."
                        ]
                    },
                    code="blank",
                )
            elif not line.get("product").get("style", None):
                raise ValidationError(
                    {"order_lines": ["Poroduct must contain style information."]},
                    code="blank",
                )
        return super(OrderSerializer, self).validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Order:
        order_lines = validated_data.pop("order_lines")

        order: Order = super(OrderSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for item in order_lines:
            item["order"] = order
            if not item.get("product").get("id", None):
                product = Product.objects.create(**item.get("product"))
                item["product"] = product
            OrderLine.objects.create(**item)

        return order


class LineSerializer(ModelSerializer[Line]):
    product = CreateProductSerializer()
    rg_id = CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "order": {"required": False},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Line:
        p_ser = CreateProductSerializer(data=validated_data.pop("product"))
        p_ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data["product"] = p_ser.save()

        return super(LineSerializer, self).create(validated_data)


class CreateProductSerializer(ModelSerializer[Product]):
    style = CreateStyleSerializer(required=False)  # type: ignore

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"

    def run_validation(self, data: Any = ...) -> Any | None:
        if not data:
            return super(CreateProductSerializer, self).run_validation(data)
        style = data.get("style", None)
        if not style:
            raise ValidationError(
                {"style": ["Product must specify a style."]},
                code="blank",
            )
        return super(CreateProductSerializer, self).run_validation(data)

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Product:
        style = validated_data.pop("style")
        s_ser = CreateStyleSerializer(data=style)
        s_ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        validated_data["style"] = s_ser.save()
        return super(CreateProductSerializer, self).create(validated_data)


class CreateStyleSerializer(ModelSerializer[Style]):
    style_files = StyleFileSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Style
        fields = "__all__"

    def run_validation(self, data: Any = ...) -> Any | None:
        svg = data.get("svg", None)
        style_files = data.get("style_files", None)
        if style_files and len(style_files) == 0:
            style_files = None
        if not svg and not style_files:
            raise ValidationError(
                {
                    "svg": [
                        "Please provide either an svg or the style_files required to generate a `Style`"
                    ]
                },
                code="blank",
            )
        return super(CreateStyleSerializer, self).run_validation(data)

    def create(self, validated_data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Style:
        style_files = validated_data.pop("style_files")
        style = super(CreateStyleSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        style_files = [{**item, "style": style} for item in style_files]
        sf_ser = StyleFileSerializer(data=style_files, many=True)
        sf_ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        sf_ser.save()
        return style
```

Apologies for a lot of code but cannot make it shorter. If it is not running then that is because I changed and posted minimized version with less (relevant) fields.

Comment: Please show how your serializer looks like.

Comment: Hej @JalilMarkel, I updated the question and provided all the serializers. I have changed the name here and there and minimized the number of fields to make things understandable.

Comment: # "file": base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode(),

I'm getting a syntax waning here.
I'm getting a typo warning here. My solution below seems to boot correctly when I fix this manually.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156766/2138283

Comment: What is `test_file` here? a file object? or a base64 file representation?

Comment: Hi @JPG. The `"file": test_file` is a file. Its not base64 as I have commented out base64 line.

Comment: @SardarFaisal, maybe its happening due to content-length mismatch? Otherwise could also try moving to Django's inbuild UploadHandler (create custom upload handler) and send json along as a text, parse on server.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve it is to have separate views to handle images and other text fields. I cannot see your views but I assume you are handling the image and the text fields in the same views.

Comment: you are right but here the problem is its a requirement. So a smart work around is required.